# Plots a blank using matplotlib & python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to plot GPS coordinates using matplotlib but by default it blots a blank canvas

```
pairs = [(lon, lat)]
plt.plot([p[0] for p in pairs], [p[1] for p in pairs])
```

but when I use

```
plt.plot([p[0] for p in pairs], [p[1] for p in pairs], 'o-')
```

it plots the canvas with dots.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: The first of those works for me too (plots a blue line). Have you changed any of the `lines` properties in your matplotlibrc by any change?

Comment: @tom : none, I am a newbie on this, is there a way to reset it to default properties, just in case I had done it by mistake...

Answer (score 0):

To plot a normal solid line you can specify only the color option.

A solid black line

```
plt.plot([p[0] for p in pairs], [p[1] for p in pairs], 'k')
```

possible colors

```
b: blue
g: green
r: red
c: cyan
m: magenta
y: yellow
k: black
w: white
```